# how to re-install postgresql in windows as I uninstalled it without removing user 'postgres'

Tags: postgresql

I uninstalled my PostgreSQl 9.1 installation without removing the user 'postgres' in windows 8.1 . Now I don't have the password for this user. While trying to reinstall,  it demands that password to continue installation. What is the workaround

as all efforts to edit hba.conf are futile because I can't reconnect as there is no installation of postgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

The postgres user by default has no password. To remove a user password (in this case for the postgres user/role):

```
alter role postgres password null;

or

alter role postgres password '';
```